# document.execCommand causes error in firefox addon-sdk

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing a Firefox extension using Firefox addon-sdk. One of my content scripts is trying to insert some text into an editable div by using this standard javascript function:

```
document.execCommand("InsertHTML", false, 'test text');
```

The above code works perfectly in my Chrome extension but fails in Firefox with this error:

**[Exception... "Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMHTMLDocument.execCommand]"  nsresult: "0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"    data: no]**

Is there any other solution to insert text at the current position into an editable div(in a content script).

Thanks in advance

Comment: The code you show above works just fine in Firefox for me.  Can you link to a page that doesn't work for you?

Comment: @BorisZbarsky it works in a simple html in firefox, but not in my firefox add-on's content script

Comment: OK, can you link to a content script that shows the problem?  Does running something similar to what you're doing in GreaseMonkey work?

Answer (score 0):

In my first glance, the function doesn't exist, resp. is not accessible:

Either due to NOT making the WHOLE doc editable (at least FF 3.5.13 shows that behaveiour) resp. 'midas' not invoked 
OR
a timing problem: the invoke of midas may take some (100?) millisec. 
In the case editability is triggerd by script or otherwise after load of page,
one should await the 'appearence' of the function (of the DOCUMENT).execCommand as
midas load-completion succeeds.

Comment: Can you please include a sample of how the code _should_ be written?